# How to send an embed with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

I was wondering how to write an embed in discord.js. This is my current code: it is not functional. I get the warning: 'message is not defined' on message.channel.send I do not know how to fix this. I was hoping you guys could tell me how to fix this. js

```js
// Embeding the image in An Embeded message
    const EmbededTweet = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('0x00FF00')
        .setTitle(`You made ${account} tweet this:`)
        .setImage(imageUrl)
        .setTimestamp();

    // replying with the Embeded message
    await interaction.reply({embeds: [EmbededTweet]});
```

Comment: Can you include the full code of the command handling function? The message.channel.send line is missing, among the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More code could be appreciated, but this is why I the error is showing up.

**Explanation**

You probably didn't declare "MessageEmbed" when you declared discord, and in your module.exports.

**How to Solve**

At the top of your code, you should have something like `const Discord = require('discord.js');` change this to `const { Discord, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');`

Feel free to reply if this didn't work, have a good day.